# Is there a way to use DirectX 11 in Windows 7?

Tags: directx, directx-11

I was trying to start to learn programming in DirectX 11, but I'm still using Windows 7 OS. My IDE is Visual Studio Community 2019 and I've tried to create a DirectX 11 project, but I got the error message saying that I need to upgrade my system to Windows 10 to be able to use this feature. I've downloaded Microsoft Development Kit, SDK and another extensions VS offered to me thinking it would actually work, but it didnt. I'm sorry if this seems a silly question, but I'm new on this and I would find it a great help if someone is able to tell me what I'm doing wrong or if there is really not other way to program in DirectX 11 on windows 7.

Comment: Direct3D 11 was introduced with Windows Vista, so yes, it should work on Windows 7 ( but not all interfaces as some are more recent). What error you get exactly, and what gives you this error.

Comment: Well, actually now it suddenly worked and I don't know why, I was trying to get it to work since yesterday, this is the project option I was chosing in VS: https://prnt.sc/va4mbu , and this is the error I was getting when trying to create the project: https://prnt.sc/va4nes (sorry, the program is in portuguese). After this I would get the message which asked me to upgrade to Windows 10. But I'm happy now it worked, thank you for your help.

Comment: C++/CX, UWP, are clearly not the average win32 app. In other words, you didn't choose the right templates. For standard win32, there’s no DirectX project template in Visual Studio. You have to use the generic win32 project and then add support for DirectX. https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template/

Comment: Well, now everything makes sense, I thought the template I was choosing was the right one, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by Simon in the comments, the "DirectX" templates built-in to VS 2019 are for Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps only which requires Windows 10.

I maintain a number of similar templates for UWP and Win32 for DirectX 11 & DirectX 12 on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates).

Windows 7 supports DirectX 11.0.

Windows 7 can support DirectX 11.1 "software features" but not "hardware features" with [KB2670838.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2670838/) Basically this means you won't get `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1`. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/platform-update-for-windows-7). Most any Windows 7 system that's updated from Windows Update should have it.

> My Win32 templates assume you have DirectX 11.1 these days. For the details on handling DirectX 11.0, see [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/).

VS 2019 can support targeting Windows 7 Service Pack 1 for Win32 desktop development. Officially Windows 7 RTM is not supported.

VS 2019 comes with the Windows 10 SDK which includes everything you need for basic Direct3D 11 system headers and libraries. You *do not* need the legacy DirectX SDK at all. That said, if your learning materials still reference legacy stuff like D3DX11, you can install it but beware there are some special setup details. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-).

> For XAudio2 on Windows 7 SP1, use the [XAudio2Redist](https://aka.ms/XAudio2Redist) instead of the legacy DirectX SDK. For XInput, you can use the basic [XInput 9.1.0](https://walbourn.github.io/xinput-and-windows-8/) which is built-in to Windows 7.

> You may want to take a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) tutorials.